# Which Microsoft applications can be extended using MEF?

Tags: .net, mef

Which Microsoft products support extension through MEF? Right now I know that Visual Studio and NuGet can be extended using MEF. Are there any others? If so, which ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MEF is a relatively new technology (pre .NET 4.0, but still relatively new), so I wouldn't imagine there are many apps outside Visual Studio that implement this extension model, yet.

Comment: I thought office did, but can't find any documentation on it.